# How can I write logical signature for ClamAV simillar as it is in YARA?

Tags: antivirus, yara

First of all, I know that yara rules can be used in combination with ClamAV, but here I have something else in my mind, so my question is; how can I write logical signature simillar as it is in YARA.

Here is an example; Let's say that I have three strings:

**A**, **B** and **C**

convert that in YARA rule:

```
strings:

$s1 = "A"
$s2 = "B"
$s3 = "C"

condition:

any of them
```

Any idea how can I achieve that with ClamAV signatures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. I was a little bit lazy to research deeper on my own, but here is an answer:

> Logical Expression
>
> This is where we will insert our boolean logic for detecting on our
>   content matches. This uses operands like "**&**" for "and", "**|**" for "or",
>   as well as "**=**", "**<**", "**>**".

So strings will be separated like:

```
(0|1|2);3c3f7068702024;68647337386870;6576616c
```

Simple as that.